# What's the best way to to a Malloc() from monotouch?

Tags: iphone, mono, xamarin.ios

I'm doing some slightly lower-level manipulations in monotouch - the kind of thing that if I was in ObjC / xcode I would use malloc to get an Int * .

My current methodology is as follows:

- Mark the method as unsafe
- add the /unsafe flag to the compiler
- Allocate a byte array
- assign it, unsafely to an IntPtr.

IE:

```
byte [] byteArray = new byte[1024].
IntPtr byteArrayPtr;
fixed (byte *_bp = byteArray) {
    byteArrayPtr = (IntPtr)_bp;
}
```

Presto, I have `byteArrayPtr` which is attached to a 1K chunk of memory, but I can't help but think that this might be a little bit of a heavy-handed approach. Is there a cleaner way to get an `IntPtr` that points to "empty pool o' memory" ?

Answer (score 5):

You should use:

```
Marshal.AllocHGlobal ()
```

if you want heap memory.

If you want stack memory you should use [stackalloc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cx9s2sy4%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), but this is memory that is only valid for the execution of the current method.   It gets automatically released when the method terminates